# Determine how many $k$ have a square root $\mod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, roots

How can I easily determine how many $k$ have a square root $\mod n$ without having to write them out?

For example, I could ask how many $1\le k\le 143$ have a square root $\mod 143$. I can look at $\mod 11$ and $\mod 13$.

$k=1,3,4,5,9$ have roots $\mod 11$ and

$k=1,3,4,9,10,12$ have roots $\mod 13$.

**If some $k$ is both a root $\mod 11$ and $\mod 13$, does that mean it's a root $\mod 11\cdot 13$?**

I know for odd prime $p$ that $x^2\equiv a \mod p$ has either $0$ or $2$ solutions (provided $a\ne 0$) and I would assume then that for any prime modulus $p$ that there are (probably?) $\frac{p-1}{2}$ roots $\mod p$?. What if instead of having a modulus of $143$, we had $2^e\cdot 143$ as a modulus for some $e\ge 1$? What happens to the number of roots?

Comment: CRT tells you that if $a$ is a square mod $p$ and a square mod $q$, with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $a$ is a square mod $pq$, and moreover, that if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ has $k$ solutions and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$ has $\ell$ solutions, then $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$ has $k\ell$ solutions.

Comment: $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ can have one solution... when $a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: ... or when $p=2$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $kl^2$ solutions mod $pq$? Where can I find a proof for that (or how to prove it myself)?

Comment: That was an extra $l$ typo (fixed); it's $k\ell$ solutions: the product. Just pair one solution mod $p$ with one solution mod $q$ and apply CRT.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what do you mean by pair them? What would pairing both roots $4$ look like mod $pq$? What about paring the $3$ and $12$?

Comment: If you know that $r^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, and you know that $s^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$, then the CRT tells you there is a unique $x\bmod pq$ such that $x\equiv r\pmod{p}$ and $x\equiv s\pmod{q}$. That means that $x^2\equiv r^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, and $x^2\equiv s^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$, and therefore $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$. That's what "pairing" means.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Since there's $0$ solutions for $10,12\mod 11$ and $1,3,4,9$ each have $2$ solutions mod $p$ and $q$, then there's $(2\cdot 2)4=16$ solutions $\mod pq$?

Comment: I was telling you how many solutions to $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$ there are, for a fixed $a$, in terms of how many solutions there are to $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$. If what you want is how to count the number $a$ for which $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$, then you need to count the number of $a$ for which *both* $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ and $x^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$ have solutions.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I want to count the number of $a$'s. That's why I said "how many $k$ have a square root $\mod n$"

Comment: And I've answered that, *and* given you additional information which apparently confused you. Also you are talking a lot about "the number of roots", which isn't really relevant (beyond knowing that whether the number is 0 or not) for determining which ones have solutions. So why are you asking about "the number of roots", if you don't actually care about the number of roots?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes I'm extremely confused. Been confused ever since I started this class. I have nearly $0$ idea what's actually happening or the meaning or purpose of most of it. If you gave me "extra" information, I'm oblivious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149859/discussion-between-cotton-headed-ninnymuggins-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: I have no interest in chat, or becoming your personal tutor.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok, thanks for the help up to that point. Tutoring isn't for everyone